# Problem calculating a functional

Tags: calculus-of-variations, functional-calculus

> Let
>
> $$J[y]=\int_0^\pi (y')^2dx, \ \ \ \  y(0)=y(\pi)=0$$
>
> which satisfies the additional condition:
>
> $$\int_0^\pi y^2dx=1$$ Find the extremals

Seemingly this seems easy to solve, but I get a problem

Use

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0$$

This gives:

$$\frac{d}{dx}2y'=0 \longrightarrow 2y'=C \longrightarrow y(x)=\frac{C}{2}x+D$$

Use initial conditions, and you get $C=D=0$!

What's is the right approach?

Thanks

Comment: The functional itself is not a full statement of the problem you have solved. Namely, using the Euler-Lagrange equation as you have is the solution to minimising/maximising the functional. The solution you obtain minimizes this functional, subject to the boundary conditions. Note they are not *initial* conditions.

Comment: Sorry, I left out an important detail! Still, how is this solved?

Comment: You have extremized the functional under no condition. To do it with the condition you can use [Lagrange multipliers](https://www.math.tamu.edu/~fnarc/m642/m642_notes/constraints_cal_var.pdf).

Comment: @md2perpe can you show this as a solution here?

Comment: May I first ask if you know what the answer should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be solved using [Lagrange multipliers](https://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Efnarc/m642/m642_notes/constraints_cal_var.pdf). I'll sketch it for you:

For an extra condition $C[y]=0$ we define $J[y;\lambda] = J[y] - \lambda\ C[y].$ In your case,
$$
J[y;\lambda]
= \int_0^\pi \left( (y')^2 - \lambda y^2 \right) \ dx + \lambda
$$
and solve this in the usual way. The Euler-Lagrange equation becomes
$y''-\lambda y=0.$

Consider the different cases $\lambda=0,$ $\lambda>0$ and $\lambda<0.$ Only for $\lambda<0$ there are solutions satisfying the boundary conditions. Those solutions have the form $y=c_n \sin nx,$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Now applying the extra condition gives $\frac12 \pi c_n^2 = 1,$ i.e. $c_n=\pm\sqrt{2/\pi},$ but only for $n\neq 0.$ For $n=0$ the condition can not be satisfied since we get the zero function.

Finally we can calculate $J[y]$ for the solutions.

Comment: The soln is $y(x)=b_k \sin kx$, your method is correct, thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

Doing variation on the extra condition gives
$$
0 = \frac{d}{d\lambda} \left. \int_0^\pi (y+\lambda\eta)^2 \ dx \right|_{\lambda=0} = \int_0^\pi y\eta \ dx
= \langle y, \eta \rangle.
$$
Thus, we may only take $\eta$ in the space orthogonal to a solution $y.$

Likewise, doing variation on the functional gives
$$
0 = \frac{d}{d\lambda} \left. \int_0^\pi (y'+\lambda\eta')^2 \ dx \right|_{\lambda=0} = \int_0^\pi y'\eta' \ dx
= -\int_0^\pi y''\eta \ dx
= -\langle y'', \eta \rangle.
$$
Thus, $y''$ must be orthogonal to $\eta$ for all $\eta$ orthogonal to $y.$

This means that $y''$ and $y$ must be parallel, i.e. $y'' = cy$ for some constant $c.$

After this the path is the same as in my first answer.